# Prove that $\sup_S f_n \to \sup_S f$ and $\inf_S f_n \to \inf_S f$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_n$ be a bounded sequence for each $n$ $\in \mathbb{N}$ and let
>   $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on a set $S$. Prove that sup$_S f_n \to$
>    sup$_S f$ and inf$_S f_n$ $\to$ inf$_S f$

My attempt: we have that if each $f_n$ is bounded on $S$, and $f_n \to f$ uniformly, then $f$ is bounded. Now I don't know how to proceed.

Can you guys give me any hint?

Comment: My guess is that you meant “bounded” instead of “limited”.

Comment: Thanks, you're right! I've edited the post. @JoséCarlosSantos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$. There is $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$ and all $x\in S$ we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. So take any $n\geq n_0$. Then:

$f_n(x)<f(x)+\epsilon\leq \sup_S f+\epsilon$

This is true for all $x\in S$, hence $\sup_S f_n\leq \sup_S f+\epsilon$.

Similarly, we have:

$\sup_S f_n\geq f_n(x)>f(x)-\epsilon$

This is true for all $x\in S$, so $\sup_S f_n\geq \sup_S f-\epsilon$.

So we proved that for all $n\geq n_0$ we have $\sup_S f-\epsilon\leq\sup_S f_n\leq\sup_S f+\epsilon$.

Comment: Hi, Mark! Thanks for the answer. I have a dumb question: In the end, we conclude that $|\sup_S f_n - \sup_S f| \leq \epsilon$. How can I get a contradiction by supposing that this afirmation is correct for "equal to $\epsilon$"? @Mark

Comment: You don't need to do that. A sequence of real numbers $a_n$ converges to $L$ if for each $\epsilon>0$ there is $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq n_0$ implies $|a_n-L|\leq\epsilon$. This definition is absolutely equivalent to the definition where we ask $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$. Let's say $a_n\to L$ by the first definition and pick some $\epsilon>0$. Choose $n_0$ which works for $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and then for all $n\geq n_0$ we have $|a_n-L|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$, a strict inequality.